# Performance testing using Selenium WebDriver, is it possible?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Problem Statement:  I have a simple test of "Successful login to web Page". This test to be carried out with 100 different username and password. Requirement is test should hit the server with 100 usernames at the same time.

Information:  Do we have to use selenium grid or RC or simple WebDriver, we are free to use any. Reading usernames & passwords from xls, or xml or parameterized junit, we are free to use whatever.

- Is this possible?
- How can we achieve this?

Comment: Try Apache jMeter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done with Selenium WebDriver. If you want to reach 100 concurrent sessions, your best choice is to use an headless browser, for example PhantomJS. [Here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/test/PerformancePhantomJsTest.java) you have a running example. This example uses JUnit, Selenium WebDriver, and [WebDriverManager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) (to handle the required binary by PhantomJS).

To fit this example into your requirements, you need to change the value of `NUMBER_OF_BROWSERS` to `100` and then change the code of the `singleTestExcution` method for your own logic (open your app and do login).

You can also do it using real browsers, e.g. Chrome (equivalent example [here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/test/PerformanceChromeTest.java)). But if you need to reach to 100 clients, this is going to be very expensive in terms of resources (CPU and memory) conmsuption.